# Finding records of actions in parallel times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a call data records table (CDRs) with about 7 million rows,
Each row holds a call record:
unique identifier, caller number, receiving number, answer_datetime and duration_in_seconds

I am looking for an efficient way of finding calls handled by the same receiving number in parallel times.
Any query I tried took too long

The table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `cdrs` (
  `global_identifier` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caller_num` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receiving_num` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_answer` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_duration` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `caller_num` (`caller_num`),
  KEY `receiving_num` (`receiving_num`),
  KEY `call_answer` (`call_answer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

The query I have already tried:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(call_answer,'%Y%m') AS Ym,
    b_num,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    SUM(call_duration) / 60 AS c_dur
FROM
(

SELECT
    ycdr.*


FROM
    cdrs ycdr
    INNER JOIN cdrs ycdr2 ON
        ycdr2.receiving_num = ycdr.receiving_num
        AND ycdr2.caller_num != ycdr.caller_num
WHERE
    ycdr2.call_answer BETWEEN
    ycdr.call_answer AND ycdr.call_answer
    AND ycdr.call_answer >= '2015-01-01'
    AND ycdr.call_answer < '2015-01-05'
GROUP BY
    ycdr.global_identifier

) a
;
```

The EXPLAIN result:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: INNER JOINing the table to itself by the criterias I specified, then grouping by the unique identifier, then grouping for counting and summing

Comment: have you checked the execution plan of your queries?

Comment: yes... not good..."Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" on 150k lines (if I limit the amount of records in advance). Impossible to actually run it

Comment: You know what's better than describing what you tried? Posting it. You know what's better than a tiny part of the explain output? The whole output...the actual result, no description of it.

Comment: Also you should specify in greater detail what parallel times means to you. Is it the highest number of parallel calls a receiving number is handling at any point in time? Or is it in a given time range, say a minute or an hour?

Comment: You're right. I elaberated

Comment: Why are you joining another table? SELECT receiving_num FROM cdrs GROUP BY receiving_num HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN call_answer >= '2015-01-01' AND call_answer < '2015-01-05' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1

Comment: I want calls that happen in parallel times, to the same number, that is the receiving number has to have to records that overlap

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do -- "finding calls handled by the same receiving number in parallel times" doesn't particularly help.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another question with sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you are trying to do and also include your query.